# Closed form of $\sum_{i=0}^n ia^i$ derivation

Tags: sequences-and-series

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Low-order_polylogarithms) says it's

$$\sum_{k=1}^n kz^k = z\frac{1-(n+1)z^n+nz^{n+1}+1}{(1-z)^2}$$

When I tried it on my own I only got as far as:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n ia^i = \frac{n(a^{n+1}-1)}{a-1}-a^n\sum_{i=0}^n(\frac{i}{a^i})$$

But then I realised that the second term is in fact $\sum_{i=0}^n (\frac{1}{a})^ii$ which is only the original problem with $z = \frac{1}{a}$ so I'm a bit stuck.

I should point out that this is a first year undergraduate maths course for engineering. That being said, I'd appreciate if you could point out what course might teach me how to solve this (or a good book).

Comment: Duplicate of [Formula for calculating $\sum_{n=0}^{m}nr^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119636/formula-for-calculating-sum-n-0mnrn), [Formula for the summation of the series $a+2a^2+3a^3+...$ upto nth term?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1698221/formula-for-the-summation-of-the-series-a2a23a3-upto-nth-term) etc.

Comment: Closed as duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure whether that was meant to be sarcastic, so I'll just note that having the question closed as a duplicate generally gives you the best, quickest answers.

Comment: Not at all! That was indeed what I was looking for! I appreciate your help, I was having a lot of trouble searching (what with variable names being different, I appreciate how the same thing could be asked over and over again). Thanks again!

Comment: The site search leaves a lot to be desired math-wise, indeed. FWIW I located the duplicates using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) as discussed [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/announcing-a-third-party-search-engine-for-math-stackexchange).

Comment: Super useful! Thanks yet again! :D